# Factoring a XOR Expression in an Equation

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, binary-operations

I have an equation like this: $(i_1 \cdot x) \oplus (i_2 \cdot x) = r$ where $i_1, i_2,$ and $r$ are known values and $\oplus$ is xor.

What I need is that same equation but expressed as $i_3 \cdot x = r$ where $i_3$ should incorporate both $i_1$ and $i_2$ in some way

By doing some tests with random values for $x$, I ended up finding that doing $(i_1\cdot x) \oplus (i_2 \cdot x)$ is the same as doing $x \cdot (i_1 \oplus i_2) + \text{remainder}$.

I got this from the distributive property which says that $a\cdot x + b\cdot x = x(a+b)$ but this doesn't seem to work with the $\oplus$ operator.

The workaround with the remainder doesn’t work for me because it adds a second unknown to the equation which I can't even predict.

Is there another way to do this or something I missed?

Comment: i1, i2 and r are "known values"... of what type of thing?

Comment: It doesn't matter, could be integers. At least that's what I used for my tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distributive law $(a \oplus b)x = ax \oplus bx$ holds. Indeed
\begin{align}
ax \oplus bx &= ax(bx)' + (ax)'bx \\
&= ax(b' + x') + (a' + x')bx \\
&= axb' + axx' + a'bx + bxx'\\
&= ab'x + a'bx\\
&= (ab' + a'b)x\\
&= (a \oplus b)x
\end{align}

The counterpart for sets is that intersection distributes over symmetric difference.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks. Do you know what happens now if we add a third item (lets say `cx`) to `ax ⊕ bx`, meaning `ax ⊕ bx ⊕ cx`. I guess this can't be equal to `(a ⊕ b ⊕ c)x`, or can it? But does this mean that `(ax ⊕ bx) ⊕ cx = ax ⊕ (bx ⊕ cx)`?

Comment: You're welcome. The answer to your two further questions is yes. Actually, $\{0, 1\}, \oplus, \cap)$ is a ring.